# VAR function in vars package of R

Tags: r, var

I am trying to use the VAR function in vars package for R. I know that in order to apply VAR methodology to time series, the set of timeseries should be stationary. As the VAR function has an argument to mention the "type" which can be "trend" or "const" or "both", does it mean it will account for non-stationarity in the timeseries, or do we still need to explicitly stationarize the time series before we use the function? If so, what is the use of the argument "type" in VAR function?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this? I can stationarize the data before applying the function but then what is the use of mentioning the  argument "type" with either "const" or "trend" or "both"? The documentation of this function is not clear about this argument's importance and I am struggling to understand this. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I've been working a little with the same package and im pretty sure that if you use "trend" you assume your time series is not stationary when you apply the VAR function. Per definition a time series can't be stationary if you have a trend. I think that's way to understand it, at least that is the assumption i'm working on.